# detect or disable multi touch gesture zoom on safari desktop

Tags: javascript, safari, touch

Is there a way to detect or disable the zoom on desktop safari which happens on pinching the touchpad. I mean the zoom where text gets blurry which is not the regular browser zoom.

I tried listening for touchstart, gesturestart without success.

Here is a jsFiddle to test it out: http://jsfiddle.net/QW9uG/

```
['gesturestart', 'mousewheel', 'touchstart', 'click'].forEach(function(type){
    var node = document.body;
    node.addEventListener(type, function(){
        console.debug(type, arguments);
    }, false);
    console.debug('listening for ', type, 'on', node);
});
```